# print legends to area chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, area-chart

I am trying to add the legends in my area chart but I have problems and I can't position them to the right of the chart, this is my code and this is my data [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fbVcmaTtmWR5tvPKuHwCbZU7Z4TGiqQ2/view?usp=sharing)

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.csv("/home/pronostico_gas.csv")
gas <- as.data.frame(df[, 1:3])

ggplot(gas) +
  geom_area(aes(x = año, y = qg),
            colour = "#E2E418", fill = "#E2E418", alpha = 0.7, show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(x = año, y = np),
            colour = "#C5B21D", size=1, linetype = "dashed", show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = gas$año) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 250, 40)) +
  labs(title = "Title", x = "año", y = "qo") +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your data by pasting the result of `dput(gas)` into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of reproducible data, this may be a help.
Place the aesthetics you want to appear in the legend within the call to `aes` and control the appearance with `scale_?_manual`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.3


gas <- data.frame(año = 2019:2042,
                  qg = runif(24, 0, 9))

gas$np = cumsum(gas$qg)

ggplot(gas) +
  geom_area(aes(x = año, y = qg, fill = "qg"),
            colour = "#E2E418", alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_line(aes(x = año, y = np, colour = "np"),
            linewidth=1, linetype = "dashed")+
  scale_colour_manual(values = "#C5B21D")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = "#E2E418")+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white"))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = gas$año) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 250, 40)) +
  labs(title = "Title", 
       x = "año", 
       y = "qo",
       colour = "Colour",
       fill = "Fill") +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 6),
        legend.position = "right")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>